# Cannot add a null child view to a Viewgroup Nativescript-Vue

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm trying to use vue-router with nativescript-vue but I get the error **Cannot add a null child view to a Viewgroup**

I followed the documentation for nativescript-vue, tried to put routers in a external file but I am getting the same error.

```
import Vue from "nativescript-vue";
import VueDevtools from 'nativescript-vue-devtools';

Vue.use(VueDevtools, { host: '10.0.0.108' })

// import router from './router';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

import Home from '../components/Home';
import Login from '../components/Login';

const router = new VueRouter({
    pageRouting: true,
    routes: [
        { path: '/home', component: Home },
        { path: '/login', component: Login },
        { path: '*', redirect: '/home' },
    ],
});

router.replace('/home');

import store from './store';

// Uncommment the following to see NativeScript-Vue output logs
Vue.config.silent = false;

new Vue({
    router,
    store,
}).$start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, integration with Vue Router is **unsupported**. Until the team resolves the issue, please use manual routing.

Source: https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/routing/vue-router/